# Script to detect if NAS is connected and if so mount Shares

Tags: macos, applescript, daemon, nas, afp

I'm trying to find a way of mounting Shares (afp) on my NAS automatically. I use logins on it to control which shares are accessible by the computer (for privacy and other reasons). When switching logins not all of the shares get re-mounted which causes problems for some of the applications I run.

What I want to do is have a script which would run every time I login to the NAS (even if it's just guest login) then this script would mount the shares.

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. This is on an OS X computer so was thinking of using applescript to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea would be to make a launchd agent to watch a folder for changes. You will want to watch the /Volumes folder because when you login to your NAS something will get mounted in the Volumes folder. Thus the watch agent will detect that something changed in the Volumes folder and it will run a script.

It's very simple. You can google about launchd and find many examples. But to setup a watch folder use something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Volumes</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
        <string>/path/to/applescript</string>
    </array>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.someName.plistFileName</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So just create a text file with the above code. Save it with an extension of ".plist". Insert a path to the applescript in the ProgramArguments section and give it a name in the Label section.

Put this plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents folder and restart your computer. Now every time something changes in the /Volumes folder the applescript will be run.

Then you just create the applescript properly. You will first need to check the Volumes folder and see if your NAS is mounted. If it is then mount any additional shares you want and if not then do nothing. You can google (or search stack overflow) how to mount shares using applescript.

Good luck.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for this. The only problem I can think of is the shares aren't automatically loaded, so they wouldn't be loaded into the /Volumes mount when the NAS is connected. Is there anyway to do something like this but monitoring connected ip addresses/DNS names?

Comment: When the NAS is connected, something will change in the volumes folder. For example, in a Finder window I can see my NAS on the network. I click on it and it logs in and gives me a folder with my user name. If I open that folder then that folder gets mounted in /Volumes... so doing it that way will work as I described. I don't know how to monitor for "connected IP addresses" so that's my best suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I have been fighting this problem on my mac for ages and believe i finally have a solution.

I have split it into two scripts:

the first one (exported in applescript editor as stay open application) runs on idle (rather than a repeat loop) and calls a second script every 10 seconds that handles the drive mounting. the errors that i check for in the first script are quite important as -128 ensures you can still quit the stay open script with right click or on osx shutdown, while the -5014 is an unknown error that unless explicitly handled pops up a dialog in my case.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--"On Idle Launch Basic Drive Mounter.app"

on idle
    try
        --script loads on startup, so first we wait 5 seconds to ensure network
        delay 5
        --run the mounter script which is on the desktop
        run script file ":Users:localusername:Desktop:Basic Drive Mounter.app"

    on error errStr number errorNumber
        --listen for the apple quit command and quit
        if the errorNumber is equal to -128 then
            quit
            return 1
        --listen for the unknown error and ignore it
        else if the errorNumber is equal to -5014 then
            return 5
        else
            --all other errors are also ignored
            return 5
        end if
    end try
    --return with a wait of 5 seconds before next idle run
    return 5

end idle
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the second script (export as an application) does the checking of the network, then tries to mount the volume using a shell mount. i originally used a finder "mount volume" and that code exists as inline comments, but I didn't like the dialog popping up on errors; even if only for a second, so i moved on to shell script.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--"Basic Drive Mounter.app"
try
    set IP_address to "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

    set IP_Valid to true

    try
        do shell script ("ping -c 2 " & IP_address)
    on error
        set IP_Valid to false
    end try

    if IP_Valid then
        tell application "Finder"
            if disk "work" exists then
            else
                try
                    do shell script "mkdir /Volumes/work"
                end try

                do shell script "mount_afp afp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/work /Volumes/work/"

                -->>finder mount volume version
                --with timeout of 1 second
                --  mount volume "afp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/work"
                --end timeout
                --<<finder mount volume version
            end if
        end tell
    end if
on error
    return 0

    -->>finder mount volume version
    --on error finder returns an error dialog which needs to be closed to go back and  retry
    --tell application "System Events"
    --  keystroke return
    --end tell
    --<<finder mount volume version
end try    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

once you have it working, drag the first script/app into your users login items, to have it automatically started when you log in. if you don't need the persistent remapping, then drag the second script/app into the login items for a single run.

Comment: Works perfect on macOS 10.12 when this did not: http://blog.grapii.com/2015/06/keep-network-drives-mounted-on-mac-os-x-using-autofs/